# Setup vpn for Chrome or Firefox

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a VPN account, I can setup it for the operating system, but I only want one of my browser to use the vpn, not other software.

So, is it possible to setup vpn in Chrome or Firefox using my vpn account? I have searched on google for a while, but didn't found a solution.

Comment: Search network proxy settings.

Answer (score 1):

I tunnel Firefox via proxy settings (socks proxy). Firefox can use its own proxy settings, but chrome uses system settings. I use ssh to create a Dynamic forwarding port. I use Cygwin but it is likely easier for most to use putty.
Hopefully this is the lead you need.